# Flask and SQLAlchemy - error binding parameter

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm fairly new to programming in general and I'm trying to build a simple website as a pet project.

It's built with python using Flask and SQLAlchemy for the db.

I'm trying to store a QR Pillow Image(as generated or later converted to PNG) in the database by converting it to a byte stream with BufferIO and then encoding it to base64 UTF-8 as a byte string (this is where I might be doing something wrong) and then storing it in a String Column in the database.

Printing the string to the console, I can't see anything wrong with it, but I'm being met with a database error and it seems I hit a wall.

I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction or if I should try something else entirely as I tried a few different methods and nothing seems to work. Thank you!

The error I`m faced with:

```
(sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO qrdb (data, qr_b64s, date, owner_id) VALUES (?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?)]
[parameters: ('test', 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASIAAAEiAQAAAAB1xeIbAAABjklEQVR4nO2aQW6kMBRE3x9bytJIOUCOYm4wZ50bNEeZA0Syl0hu1SzAnSa9mGxoaLAXH7Ce5BL6KsoWJv4_hl8_gKBRjWpUoxq1d ... (310 characters truncated) ... q50xhxy2KypyCmuesSuX5rN6sq_n-drd_9a9J-W_PInem4WM0wZWWc55I3eV78pus34muI1IP55jkbs73hNFa369IPZxjQs33SrR8vyZl7d-oRjWqUY06BfUPhs3JLUffqKQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=', <User 1>)]
```

The generator function:

```
def enq(data):
    qr = qrcode.make(data)
    img_buffer = BytesIO()
    qr.save(img_buffer, format='PNG')
    byte_data = img_buffer.getvalue()
    b64s = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(byte_data)
    string = str(b64s, 'UTF-8')
    return string
```

Posting to DB:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    data = request.form.get('data')
    
    if len(data) < 1:
        flash('Data too short!', category='error')
    else:
        new_qr = Qrdb(qr_b64s=codegen.enq(data), data=data, owner_id=current_user)
        db.session.add(new_qr)
        db.session.commit
        print('Qr added to DB.')
```

Database model:

```
class Qrdb(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    qr_b64s = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
new_qr = Qrdb(qr_b64s=codegen.enq(data), data=data, owner_id=current_user)
```

should be

```
new_qr = Qrdb(qr_b64s=codegen.enq(data), data=data, owner_id=current_user.id)
```

because `Qrdb.owner_id` is an *integer* column.  If you change the `Qrdb` model to add a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationships.html) to the `User` model then you could pass a `User` instance instead of an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I will make the due changes to the ```new_qr``` variable.  Do you have any idea why I can't bind the byte string to the ```qr_b64s``` column?

Comment: I don't have any problem binding that column - `parameter 2` in the error message refers to the owner/user.

Comment: Can you please explain why that might be? Any way I look at it, to me, ```parameter 2``` seems to be the byte string.  I will run the program with the ```new_qr``` change once I get home from work.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I don't know the details of the implementation, but at a guess, it only counts values which are variables (so not the keyword `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and uses zero-based counting, so the third variable, `owner_id` is at index 2).

Comment: Many thanks to @snakecharmerb, you were right, the issues I was facing were all due the missing `.id` . It`s all working now, thanks again!